# Where can I find help?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

By going to the different stuff here, I was wondering, if there shouldn't be a help section in Stack Overflow?

Comment: If only there were some kind of repository of questions other people had asked many times about the site.  You know, just the most frequent ones.  Or, better yet, a whole second site just for questions about this site!  That would be great!

Answer (score 1):

There is. It's called [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

<sub>(Yes it is where you are now reading this question)</sub>.

Everything tagged with [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) should be what your looking for.

<sub>You would think people are born under a bush just throwing software out there without any way to help their users. So typical of developers</sub>